# How to convert a three address code to MIPS Assembly language?

Tags: c++, assembly, compiler-construction, mips

I am doing a project in which I have to create a translator that would generate a MIPS assembly code for a C code. The programming language that am using is C++ and I have done till generation of three address code and am really confused about how to proceed further.

Comment: 3 address code?  Can you clarify?  (And I've removed the compiler-optimization tag on your question.  Considering it's not yet fully working, I'm assuming you're not optimizing.)

Comment: Start with finding a translation for one 3-address instruction, say `add`. Can you find an equivalent in the list of MIPS instructions? Perhaps an approximate equivalent?

Comment: @user - You have to look at each 3-address instruction and figure out how you would do that in assembly. Then produce one or more assembly instructions.

Comment: Yes,even i am thinking about taking one instruction at a time, but i am not getting a clear picture about it and about compiler optimization, to generate a assembly code from intermediate code(three address code) you need to optimize it first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As already stated, it's a direct translation. There's really nothing to clarify. As an example, take the following three-address code:

```
      i := 0                  ; assignment
L1:   if i >= 10 goto L2      ; conditional jump
      t0 := i*i
      t1 := &b                ; address-of operation
      t2 := t1 + i            ; t2 holds the address of b[i]
      *t2 := t0               ; store through pointer
      i := i + 1
      goto L1
L2:
```

The MIPS translation is:

```
        li $t0, 0             #allocator assigned i to t0
L1:     bge $t0, 10, L2    
        mult $t1, $t0, $t0  
        la $t2, b             
        add $t3, $t2, $t0   
        sw $t1, ($t3)       
        addi $t0, $t0, 1
        j L1
L2:
```

If your lucky enough to have three-address like that, you barely have to do anything. Find the corresponding opcode to go with the instruction. The register allocation has already been done. If the three-address code is literally a bunch a strings, I'd consider writing a small parser (using a generator) instead of trying to extract information from the strings.